# Polymer 0.8 Shady DOM

Tags: css, polymer, shady-dom

Does the Shady DOM introduced with Polymer 0.8 prevent styles from being leaked into the local DOM or is that something only the Shadow DOM can do?

https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/devguide/experimental.html#xscope-styling

In the following example, would the Shady DOM prevent the title from becoming red?

**my-element.html**

```
<template>
    <span class="title">{{title}}</span>
</template>
```

**styles.css**

```
.title {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been testing Polymer 0.8 and so far it seems it doesn't. The shadow boundary rules are not upheld, as it scopes styles defined in the `<dom-module>` to the Polymer element, but does not stop leaking from the external stylesheet. There docs here imply that, though I wouldn't say they've explicitly stated it: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#scoped-styling

Edit: I'm guessing this'll be fixed in 0.9 or 1.0, see [this post](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/01/polymer-state-of-the-union). Though I find there last point on [this part](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/#highlights) to suggest it should be available now, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I found when testing as well -- just wanted to make sure it wasn't due to user error.  The docs, do imply that, so that's why I'm confused.